# Does this work to show that $\int_0^{1-1/n}f_n(x)dx\to\int_0^1f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, uniform-convergence

This question comes from *Tom M. Apostol's Mathematical Analysis* I'm not sure which edition, it is the exercise 13-14. The question is the following (my book is in Spanish and I'm translating back to English, so I'm sorry if the translation it's not accurate.)

> Let $\lbrace f_n\rbrace$ be a sequence of continuous real functions defined in the interval $[0,1]$ and suppose $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$. Determine if the following is true or not.
> $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{1-1/n}f_n(x)dx = \int_0^1f(x)dx.
> $$

I have already solve it, the answer being that it is true, but I want to know if the following approach could work. **I'm not looking for an alternate solution**.

For each natural number $n$ let $F_n(x) := \int_0^xf_n(t)dt$ and $F:=\int_0^xf(t)dt$. (note that $F_n$ is continuous for every $n$).

Since $f_n\to f$ uniformly, we know that $F_n\to F$ uniformly. (and so $F$ is also continuous).

What we want to prove is the same as
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(1-1/n)-F_n(0) = F(1)-F(0)
$$
We already know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(0)=F(0)$ so its left to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(1-1/n)=F(1)$.

We have the following
\begin{align}
F(1)
&=\lim_{x\to 1^-}F(x)\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(x)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to 1^-}F_n(x)\\
\end{align}
Where the first equality holds because $F$ is continuous, the second one because $F_n\to F$ and the third one because the convergence of $\lbrace{F_n}\rbrace$ is uniform.

Now, since each $F_n$ is continuous we have that
$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}F_n(x) = \lim_{m\to\infty}F_n(1-1/m)
$$
So
$$
F(1) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}F_n(1-1/m)
$$
Could we use this to show what we want?
In other words, can we prove that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}F_n(1-1/m)=\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(1-1/n)
$$
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You should look for an alternative solution as an elegant one exists.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think so. I do not agree with the equality:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}F_n(1-1/m)=\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(1-1/n) $$
If you use the Monotone Convergence Theorem, then it holds. However, you need something else before you plug in the equality.

Answer (score -1):

Can it be shown like this? Please feel free to comment if it has any flaws.

Given any $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $x \in [0,1]$
$$\mid f_n(x)-f(x)\mid < \epsilon,\ \forall\ n\geq N.$$
Now we can estimate
\begin{align}
\left| \int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{n}}(f_n(x)-f(x))dx \right| &\leq \int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{n}}\mid f_n(x)-f(x)\mid dx\\
&\leq \int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{n}}\epsilon\ dx\ (\ \forall n\geq N)\\
&=\epsilon\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{align}
Therefore we will have $\lim_{n\to \infty}  \left| \int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{n}}(f_n(x)-f(x))dx \right|\leq \epsilon$ and hence $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{n}}(f_n(x)-f(x))dx=0$$ i.e., $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{n}}f_n(x)dx-\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{n}}f(x)dx=0$$ and hence
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{n}}f_n(x)dx= \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx.$$